# What type of berry is this?

Tags: identification, berries, outdoor

[image]

Bought this plant in a local supermarket but cannot remember what it is. The berry itself looks like a small raspberry but shiny like a blackberry. It tastes sweet.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this looks very much like a wineberry.  It's a type of raspberry.  Wineberries are one of my favorite raspberries and one of the only I've ever seen that produce reliably in the shade.  It is considered semi invasive in some areas so just beware.

Comment: Interesting - never seen this before, but apparently some people grow them even in the UK.Do they taste like raspberries?

Comment: Yeah they do.  They're a little different than a typical raspberry though.  Wineberries I think, are less tart and really sweet but are slightly less firm.  They're easily smooshed which is, I've always assumed, why they would be used for wine making.

Comment: 'Easily smooshed' I know exactly what you mean, wild blackberries are like that here, you can smoosh those when you pick them if you're not careful. Thanks - doesn't sound they taste like any kind of wine then!